# ionic 4 how to add svg icon dynamically like- {title: 'About', url: '/about' , icon:'person'}

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

{title: 'About', url: '/about' , icon:'person'} like this how to add custom svg icon

{title: 'mobile', url: '/about' , icon:'custom-mobile'}

ion-icon { &[class*="custom-"] { mask-size: contain; mask-position: 50% 50%; mask-repeat: no-repeat; background: currentColor; width: 1em; height: 1em; }

&[class*="custom-mobile"] { mask-image: url(../assets/mobile.svg); } } ---tried this also, not working in ionic 4---

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear where you're talking about using it but the IonIcons has [documentation about custom icons](https://ionicons.com/usage#basic-usage):

> To use a custom SVG, provide its url in the `src` attribute to request the external SVG file. The `src` attribute works the same as `<img src="...">` in that the url must be accessible from the webpage that's making a request for the image. Additionally, the external file can only be a valid `svg` and does not allow scripts or events within the `svg` element.

So the snippet would look like this:

```
<ion-icon src="/path/to/external/file.svg"></ion-icon>
```

And if you want to do it dynamically its like this:

```
<ion-icon [src]="variablewithimagepath"></ion-icon>
```